# How to use SampleGrabber with Matroska Muxer in DirectShow?

Tags: directshow, mkv, matroska, samplegrabber, graphedit

I made a simple graph to write MKV file. But I do not want to use file writer. I want to use SampleGabber and get stream using simple program. Problem is that I get data from anything but Matroska muxer!( What shall i do?

[image: VirtualCamera - x264 - Matroska Muxer - SampleGraber - Null Renderer]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/CO/MkvAndSampleGrabber.jpg))</sub>

So my question is How to use SampleGrabber with Matroska Muxer in DirectShow?

Comment: BTW: I use VirtualCamera from here http://www.soundmorning.com/download.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing you own custom renderer instead of SampleGrabber.

Comment: could you share some resources on HOW TO DO SUCH THING?

Comment: Basically you create your own class derived from CBaseVideoRenderer. Then you have to implement your own: DoRenderSample method which will be called on every new sample filter receives.
To add your renderer to the graph:
CMyVideoRenderer *pRenderer = new CMyVideoRenderer(NULL, &hr);
CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pBaseTarget = pRenderer;
m_pGB->AddFilter(pBaseTarget, L"MYRENDERER"));